# Upgrading dependant libraries when updating jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Let's say I'm upgrading jQuery from 1.7.1 to 1.11.1

Among the changes between those 2 versions, there is the $.browser (removed in 1.9)

Let's say I also have jQuery-UI 1.8.20, which contains a few lines with $.browser (and maybe other methods changed or removed?)

Where can I find which version of jQuery-UI will work with jQuery 1.11.1?

The only thing I found searching the web was a Wikipedia page, listing which version of jQuery is required for which jQuery-UI version...  For UI 1.8.20 it only says "1.3.2+"... well, jQuery 1.9 is greater than 1.3.2 but, having removed $.browser, would break UI 1.8.20??

The problem would also occur with other dependant libraries, such as **jCarousel** or **qtip2**, which often simply list "jQuery 1.3+" as requirement.

The *"v X.X or greater"* requirement wording seems weak, I think, considering removal of methods and functions in jQuery core will eventually break it.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick fix, look at the jQuery-migrate project

Comment: Yes, I will definitely use this plugin